# R lapply-split-rbindlist - does subset cause problems?

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

I'm sure this will be very easy as I'm still an R beginner but here goes...

I've started with a data frame which I've successfully put through lapply-split followed by rbindlist to regenerate as a dataframe.

From this same data set, I've subset some data and performed lapply-split followed by rbindlist and get the following error:

> "Error in rbindlist(df) :    Item 1 of list input is not a data.frame,
>   data.table or list"

This is confusing since it's the same (sub)set of data being split by the same parameter.

When I call:

```
df[1]
```

I get:

```
$SWS1Ami
[1] 13451.02
```

which is the mean value I wanted to calculate for the SWS1Ami group (so it seems to have done the lapply split correctly). When I call:

```
typeof(df[1])
```

I see it tells me this element(?) type is a list.

Two questions:
(1) What could cause rbindlist to not work after doing lapply-split? Why does this seem to sometimes work and sometimes not work?

(2) Is there a quick litmus test to tell if your dataframe is in the "right" setup to undergo lapply-split-rbindlist?

Comment: `rbindlist` isn't looking at `df[1]`. It's looking at `df[[1]]`, which to me looks like an atomic vector.  It would help to have a reproducible example.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what the difference is between df[1] and df[[1]]? I can add the workaround I've found I've had to use is:                     > df1<-as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, df1))
>setDT(df1, keep.rownames = TRUE)[ ]

Comment: I'm not going to do that.  It's already in `help(Extract)` ready for you :)

Comment: `df[1]` returns a list, as you can see with the `$WS1Ami` where as `df[[1]]` returns the content of the list (ie in this case the atomic value 14341.02)

Comment: Does the subset of the factor you split the dataset by contain an empty factor level? (e.g. `as.factor(letters[1:3])[1:2]`) In this case split produces one list element with a data.frame with 0 rows, depending on the function you apply with lapply this could be a problem.
In this case call `factor` again on the factor variable after subsetting.